# UIBarButtonItem not firing when clicked

Tags: objective-c, ios7, xcode5

I am having some trouble with my bar buttons.  I have two buttons for clear and log out.  When i click them nothing happens.  But if i hold down on the button for 3-5 seconds and release than the action gets fired.  Can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong here?

This is the only code for it.

```
- (IBAction)clear:(id)sender
{
    [self clearFields];
}
```

Comment: Are you using a long press gesture recognizer for this?

Comment: Not that i know of.  I just add the button and Ctrl dragged it to get the action in the header.

Comment: please can you share some piece of code.so,that we can try to help you out.

Comment: There really is not much code for it.  The only code for the button i just put above.  The only thing i did was add a toolbar, add a UIBarButton to the tool bar, ctrl dragged it to the header, and created an IBAction.